# updating html percentage in text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the HTML element below:

```
<div class="progressbar-text" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2rem;">84%</div>
```

I want to be able to use javascript to set 84% to 70%.

I tried:

```
let data = document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar-text")[0];
data.innerText = "70%";
```

This does not change anything in the page render. Am I doing something wrong? BTW, when I go inspect the element and manually change the 84% it works fine.

Comment: If the document is not ready, sometimes you won't be able to query the element.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h2oeLjkm/

Comment: Why you've used `vue.js` tag, since you're using vanilla JS

Comment: your code works fine when i tested it

Comment: Please post code for a minimal reproducible question. The code you posted is not enough to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

what is your javascript position，
this code i hope can to help you：

```html
<div class="progressbar-text"
        style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2rem;">
        84%</div>
    <script>
        let data = document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar-text")[0];
        data.innerText = "70%";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
const update = document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar-text");
update.setAttribute("style", "left: 50%; top: 50%;")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<input type="range" id="radio" value="1" min="0" max="100"/>
<p id="para"></p>

//script
<script>
  let range = document.getElementById("range");
  Let para = document.getElementById("para").
     para.innerHTML = range.value;

     range.oninput = function() {
         para.innerHTML = range.value;
     }

 </script>
```